# Conditional For loop is not working in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Conditional  For loop is not working in batch file

When i write condition in for loop,the condition is working but after the condition i want to print the values in  for loop but it was not displaying the  values and here below is  my script

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in (rule.txt) do (
 findstr select rule.txt(
 mysql  --user u --password p --database d -e  "%%a">>Query.txt
 )
 echo %%a
 )
```

**data in rule.txt**

```
select 
replace
direct
```

In for loop,the findstr function is woking but it was not printing the values after the findstr function. Actually,it will able to display all data which was in rule.txt right! when i write  **echo %%a**?
     but  it is not displaying the expected result ? i didn't understand where the problem occurs can someone plz help me

Expected Result:

```
select 
replace
direct
```

Comment: because you do not assign the findstr output as tokens/variables.

Comment: sry, can u explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `findstr` as part of the loop, in order for you to assign the result to the token, in this case being `%%a`:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('type somefile.txt ^|findstr "select"') do echo %%a
```

I am not making sense of why you want to search for an exact word, then just add it to an output as you could have just added the word to the string, but nevertheless. I think this is what you intended:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('type somefile.txt ^|findstr "select"') do (
  mysql  --user u --password p --database d -e  "%%a">>Query.txt
  echo %%a
)
```

Your expected result however does not match your findstr of `select` Did you perhaps mean to output each of the lines to file? if so, then this will do it.:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (somefile.txt) do (
  mysql  --user u --password p --database d -e  "%%a">>Query.txt
  echo %%a
)
```